# Install local library

Tags: haskell, cabal

How can I "install" a local (ie it is on my hard-drive, not on the internet) .hs file to use it across multiple programs? Specifically, if I edit the library, those edits should be available to all programs, so no copy-pasting the library into every program’s directory.

To compile my programs, I still want to type ghc main.hs, not a page of file-paths.

This may be obvious from the above, but I don’t have any knowledge of cabal.

Comment: 1. Learn how to cabalize your package 2. `cabal install`.

Comment: Ok, I’ll copy-paste then. It’s a mess but it works at least.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the proper Haskell platform installed, including `cabal`. Alternatively you can use [`stack`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/), which is more modern and in many ways better, but IMO `cabal` is still more practical for a simple project like yours.
   The following assumes you use `cabal` on a typical Linux machine.
2. If not already done, give your file a meaningful *hierarchical module name*, according to what it does. `module Video.Demuxing.FFMPEG` or `Data.List.Shuffle.Deterministic`, for example. Let's assume you call it `Foo.Bar.Baz`. I.e. the file should begin with

   ```
   module Foo.Bar.Baz where
   ... -- start code
   ```
3. Put the file in a corresponding folder structure, i.e.

   1. if not already done, make a new project directory, for example

      ```
      mkdir /home/Uꜱᴇʀɴᴀᴍᴇ/haskell/foobar
      cd /home/Uꜱᴇʀɴᴀᴍᴇ/haskell/foobar
      ```
   2. In that project directory make a subdirectory `Foo`, therein a directory `Bar`, and put your file in it as `Baz.hs`.

      ```
      mkdir -p Foo/Bar
      cp WʜᴇʀᴇEᴠᴇʀ/Yᴏᴜʀ/Fɪʟᴇ/Wᴀꜱ/Bᴇꜰᴏʀᴇ.hs Foo/Bar/Baz.hs
      ```
4. Make the file part of a new cabal library.

   ```
   cabal init
   ```

   This will ask you a couple of questions, hopefully it'll be clear what to choose. For the most part, the defaults will be fine, in that case always just press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
5. Put everything under *version control*, if you haven't already. (If you don't know what this is, I suggest you read some Github tutorials. You can skip this step, but the sooner you accustom yourself to some VCS, the better.)
6. Install your project locally.

   ```
   cabal install
   ```
7. If everything has worked without errors, you can then, in a Haskell file stored in somewhere else on the computer, simply

   ```
   import Foo.Bar.Baz
   ```

   and have everything availably you've defined in that project module. No need to tell GHC where `Foo.Bar.Baz` is stored when compiling, it has already registered that at this point. You can also launch up ghci anywhere and `:m +Foo.Bar.Baz`.

Comment: after asking for source directory, cabal init complains (Warning) about missing dependencies--librarys that I do not import, like Text.Parsec, Crypto.MAC.SipHash, Graphics.UI.Threepenny.

Comment: Aha. Sound like a topic for a separate question.